# Grails project run error -Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: grails

**Error |
Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use: JVM_Bind (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)**

When I going to execute my grails project second time using 
--- **2 Grails Command(run-app)** struck with this type of error each and every time.

But when I kill the javaw.exe using Task Manager then if I will run again it works for me. Is there any permanent solution for this?..pls suggest.

> |Packaging Grails application ..
>
> |Compiling 10 source files ..
>
> |Compiling 121 source files .......
>
> |Compiling 9 source files .........................
>
> |Running Grails application
>
> Error | Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use:
>   JVM_Bind (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: What about shutting down the server, before executing "run-app" again?

Comment: How to shut down(Stop) the currently executing server in GGTS tool.?

Comment: I believe that there's a stop button in the "Console" output, look for a red rectangle.

Comment: Ya I found that but is there need to stop every time before start project? pls suggest.

Comment: I typically run one application/project at the time. I suggest using either "server.port" JVM argument or specifying "grails.server.port.http" in BuildConfig.groovy for each project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the HTTP port to run the server using the cli:

Example:

```
grails -Dserver.port=8090 run-app
```

More details in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html)

Comment: Grails 2.3.8 is currently in use.                                    Thanks so much, But When I used to run my project using **'2 Grails Command(run-app)'** it again show me same error message.               What is the use of 'grails -Dserver.port=8090 run-app'

Comment: If you're using Grails/Groovy Tool Suite ( Eclipse based IDE ), select **Run as > Run Configurations.... Then, in Grails tab,** input like this :

**-Dserver.port=8050 run-app**
So, Grails will run on port 8050 instead of the default port (8080).

Comment: With this command, you can run run one server on port 8080 and the second server on port 8090.

Comment: I got this error too - _[Fatal Error] :55573:4: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity._

Comment: This error is not related with your first question. But you can try a "grails clean" to delete all compiled resources from the application. (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/clean.html). If necessary, you can open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the app for the first time, it will continue to run until you explicitly tell it to stop. Regardless of how you start the app (whether it be from GGTS or command prompt) until you send the command `stop-app` it will continue.  You get the error you have been encountering:

```
Error | Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use: JVM_Bind (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

when that server is still running.  Grails will compile your changes as you make them, and you are able to see the results on your web page right away (for most changes, making changes to your domain objects can be problematic, and often will require you restart your server).

Personally I prefer to edit the project in GGTS but use a console to manage the app simply because I prefer the error output from the console instead of GGTS.

Answer (score 1):

With latest version of Grails (from 2.3.0), default setting is to run the server in forked mode. You can find this config in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.fork = [ ... ]
```

With the above forked mode enabled for `run-app`, app has to be stopped explicitly before re-run. Therefore, `grails stop-app` has to be issued before `grails run-app`.

If you do not want to run app in forked mode, then replace this line with `run:false`:

```
run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false]
```

With that, there will not be a need to explicitly run the `stop-app` command.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is fork and what is need of this in my project. What if I not use this?

Comment: Refer [**Grails documentation**](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode).

Answer (score 0):

Open BuildConfig.groovy

Solution 1 : 
then replace this line with run:false
run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, **debug: false**, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],

Solution 2 : 
comment Previous line

Comment: If I comment out existing run line with run:false then what happed ? Why that run line is mentioned by default if we need to change that one?  Could you please specify and get me cleared about all this....thnks ..:)

Comment: solution 1: Can you specify what line he is supposed to replace with what? solution 2: comment what previous line?